# Oracle MINUS operator and delete

Tags: oracle

You can insert records into table B if they are in table A

```
insert into B
select * from A
minus
select * from B
```

How do you delete records that are in B and not in A?

```
select * from B
minus 
select * from A
```

How to delete records?

The assumption is that we do not have a primary key or a unique one.

You can do it like this:

```
delete from a2
where (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, ...) in (select * from a2
                     minus
                    select * from a1);
```

It works, but you have to enter the column names in the where clause. Can not do delete in such a beautiful way as `insert into select * from ...`?

Comment: The best solution here is to just have a primary key, with a foreign key relationship.

Comment: These are not tables in the database, they are reports (views) that do not have keys - and even if they have it, I do not want to identify them. The assumption is that the rows are unique.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to continue with your current approach, you should *not* use `select *` in your minus query.  Rather, you should *always* explicitly list out the columns which you want to use.

But, I would use an `EXISTS` query here:

```
DELETE
FROM tableB b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tableA a
                  WHERE a.col1 = b.col1 AND
                        a.col2 = b.col2 AND
                        a.col3 = b.col3 AND ...);
```

Best practice going forward would to have a primary key column in the A table.  Then, you would only need to check that column against the B table for uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this way also requires a list of columns - and I asked if anyone knows the option to not give it. Second thing, tables should of course and must contain unique keys including master keys. But these are not tables in the database, they are views with reports, various reports that do not contain such keys - I do not want to search for them, because the rows are unique.

Comment: My answer does not change based on your comment.